# Actual difference between rs 343B and rs 343A

Tags: video

What is the actual difference between rs 343A and rs343b? in terms of signal voltage, the number of lines and the specificiations.

regards

Answer (score 1):

ANALOG CLOSED-CIRCUIT SIGNALS (RS-330, RS343, RS-412)

Later, in the 60’s, the EIA added several high-resolution monochrome closed-circuit standards RS-330, RS-343, and RS-412.  These standards are still being used in military applications today.  NATO (and others) have added various tweaks to the original EIA standards to produce special purpose defense system formats such as STANAG (A, B, & C), HOBO, and MAVERIK

In wikipedia :

EIA-343 Formerly RS-343. Signal standard for non-broadcast high resolution monochrome video.

EIA-343A Formerly RS-343 A. Video signal standard for high resolution monochrome CCTV. Based on EIA-343.

STANAG 3350 Class A:875 Lines,60 Frames/Sec,Base on RS-343 RGB,now EIA343A

STANAG 3350 Class B:625 Lines,50 Frames/Sec,Base on PAL

STANAg 3350 Class C:525 Lines,60 Frames/Sec,Base on NTSC RS-170A

Comment: yes i know that but that the version b of rs343 that is puzzling

Comment: i mention at end of answer Class B is  625 Lines,50 Frames/Sec,Base on PAL

Comment: So if class B is PAL, is class A NTSC?

Comment: no Class A is RGB Class C is NTSC

Comment: Does is rs343a is colored(require 3 inputs) while rs343b is monchrome

Comment: my meaning is STANAG 3350 Class A is RGB timing base on rs343a , rs343 has RGB too as far as I know We haven't   rs343b we have EIA-370-B or STANAG 3350 Class B